# 3D map view in QGIS with .grd format bathemetry data

Tags: qgis, 3d

I am attempting to use the 3D map feature available in QGIS3 for viewing bathymetry data. These data are in .grd format, but I’ve also tried using data in GeoTiFF format with no luck.

The 3D map comes up blank, and no amount of scrolling brings the panel into view. I’ve checked that this feature does, in fact, work with .hgt (SRTM) elevation data.

I’m not super familiar with the differences between different data formats (.tif, .grd, .hgt, etc...) but my thinking is that these data are either missing some information or need to be converted to .hgt.

I do know that conversion to .hgt is possible, but it has some drawbacks that I’d like to avoid.

Has anyone encountered this problem and know of a possible solution?

EDIT: [Here are some data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JYFym3ZyzCw3INCvAB1iyLr4B4ta_LzA)

Comment: Provide test data.

Comment: You can select option `Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)` and choose `WGS84`(EPSG:4326)` for CRS.